# Should we Always/Sometimes use ".Cells" property in "For Each" Loops

Tags: excel, vba

I always use `For Each r In rng.Cells` rather than `For Each r In rng`. I remember in the past dealing with problems by explicitly using the `.Cells` property. I was challenged a few times in this forum that `.Cells` is not necessary in `For Each` loops and because I couldn't remember an example where I needed to explicitly use `.Cells` I reluctantly accepted that it was not necessary.

However, today I came across a situation where I had to explicitly use `.Cells` to get the expected behaviour:

```vb
Sub TestCellsProperty()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim i As Long: i = 2
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:B2")
    
    Debug.Print "*****Case 1: rng"
    For Each r In rng
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next r
    
    Debug.Print "*****Case 2: rng.Rows(" & i & ")"
    For Each r In rng.Rows(i)
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next r
    
    Debug.Print "*****Case 3: rng.Rows(" & i & ").Cells"
    For Each r In rng.Rows(i).Cells
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next r
    
    Debug.Print "*****Case 4: rng.Columns(" & i & ")"
    For Each r In rng.Columns(i)
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next r
    
    Debug.Print "*****Case 5: rng.Columns(" & i & ").Cells"
    For Each r In rng.Columns(i).Cells
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

The output I got:

```
*****Case 1: rng
$A$1
$B$1
$A$2
$B$2
*****Case 2: rng.Rows(2)
$A$2:$B$2
*****Case 3: rng.Rows(2).Cells
$A$2
$B$2
*****Case 4: rng.Columns(2)
$B$1:$B$2
*****Case 5: rng.Columns(2).Cells
$B$1
$B$2
```

It seems that and explicit use of `.Cells` property is necessary with `Rows(i)` and `Columns(i)`.

I guess I have two questions:

1. Why is this happening? after all `.Rows(i)` and `.Columns(i)` result in `Range` objects and using them in `For Each` loops should really loop through all the cells without having to explicitly use the `.Cells` property.
2. Should one conclude that it is safer to always use the `.Cells` property to avoid these unintuitive situations?

Comment: Anyone who tells you that explicitly specifying a property is *wrong* should probably be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should we Always/Sometimes use “.Cells” property in “For Each” Loops

It depends on what you want to achieve.

1. Do you want to loop through cells?
2. Do you want to loop through rows?
3. Do you want to loop through columns?
4. Do you want to loop through areas?

When you say `For Each r In rng.Rows(i)` or `For Each r In rng.Columns(i)`, then you are telling excel to loop through **every row and column in that range**. When you say `For Each r In rng`, then you are telling excel to loop through **every range in that range**. In this case `.Cells` is not necessary but when you are looping through rows and columns and you want the cell address then yes, you have to use `.Cells` else you will get the row or column address.

See this detailed example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:B2")
    
    For Each r In rng                   '<~~ loop through every range in that range
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "------"
    
    For Each r In rng.Rows(1)           '<~~ loop through every row in that range
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next r
    
    '~~> Note the above actually doesn't make sense because you are limiting it to
    '~~> 1st row. If you want to loop through rows then the below is what you want
    
    Debug.Print "------"
    
    For Each r In rng.Rows              '<~~ loop through every row in that range
        Debug.Print r.Address
    Next r
    
    Debug.Print "------"
    
    '~~> .Rows(1) makes sense here as you want to loop through cell in that row
    For Each r In rng.Rows(1)           '<~~ loop through every row in that range
        For Each aCell In r.Cells       '<~~ loop through every range in that row
            Debug.Print aCell.Address
        Next aCell
    Next r
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
$A$1
$B$1
$A$2
$B$2
------
$A$1:$B$1
------
$A$1:$B$1
$A$2:$B$2
------
$A$1
$B$1
```

Of course

```
For Each r In rng.Rows(1)           '<~~ loop through every row in that range
    For Each aCell In r.Cells       '<~~ loop through every range in that row
        Debug.Print aCell.Address
    Next aCell
Next r
```

is nothing but

```
For Each r In rng.Rows(1).Cells     '<~~ loop through every range in row 1
    Debug.Print r.Address
Next r
```